# Having trouble in getting the author details inside contact form 7 wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form

I have created a author page in wp where it displays the details of the particular author , the details are fetched from the users role option in wp.. Now I need to have a contact form in that page in a pop up when the button is clicked it should display the contact form and automatically fetch and display the user mail id under "TO" section..

To display the author details in that page template I have used "`<?php the_author(); ?>`", like wise I need to use the code `<?php the_author(); ?>` inside the contact form 7 do automatically generate the "to" address.

Thank you in advance..

Comment: try to set up a empty field in contact form and dynamically set author values using a javascript.

Comment: I tried to use the following method 
`$author = get_the_author();` and included the `$author` in CF7 but am not able to fetch the value for the variable $author

Comment: you can't do so. But you can bind those values using jquery at runtime.